# Severe screen noise

Tags: troubleshooting, nvidia-graphics-card

https://youtu.be/uFByqTYc2MY

Upon turning on the PC I was greeted with this. Windows boots only in safe mode and with lots of noise all over the screen. There were no hardware changes or issues for the last 5 years. Is it safe to say that the video card is the culprit? Just don't want to spend money to realize it was a waste.

Comment: Something FREE to try from the actual PC or laptop.... `1.` Reseat the RAM memory chip module(s) and reboot to see if that makes a difference... `2.` Take the RAM memory from the device and try with once RAM chip at a time or none, or whatever combination you're working with for this device. Just try some of these and see what happens, these are freebies and you might be surprised. You might reseat the video card and anything else within the device that you can unplug and plug back in. Try from a different electrical source too and away large magnets, magnetic forces, etc. if applicable.